# Why does UILabel's font and color get changed for few screens in my app, when Device font is changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uilabel

When device font size is changed, it reflects on my app for few screens; also changing the font color.

Changing the device font size:Settings->Display & Brightness ->Text Size 
is changing the UI of my app for few screens.

I am not getting this issue for iOS 7.x and earlier versions.
This issue is coming only for iOS 8.x in iPad Air.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    myCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[myCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:kMasterSelectionColor]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:kOrangeColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kHelveticaNeueLight size:kFontSize18];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:kWhiteColor];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @“text”;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: maybe you are using system font for those labels

Comment: Post a before and after image that shows the problem. Also, you do know that your app should support Dynamic Type (user changeable font size) since iOS 7 right?

Comment: No @johny kumar  , I am not using system font. Used custom font and custom color.

Comment: Is the label is of Attributed text?

Comment: @vani , No. Its text only, I am using UITableViewCell.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with reusing a table view cell? Can you post some source code? How do you set the color?

Comment: @freytag, I added source code, please check it.